# Spring bulk update fields with id's matching the given list

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to do multiple updates in my DB based on the provided id.Right now I am iterating the id List and calling the update function of my repository again and again.However this is not efficient.I want to know if there is a way I can do bulk updates in one rest call by passing the id List and the other new field value list as parameter.Thanks in advance for the help.

Right now I'm calling this method again and again to update the values.However this is not at all efficient:

```
 @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Student c SET c.rollNo= :rollNo WHERE c.id = :id")
    void updateStudentRollNo(@Param("id") long id, @Param("rollNo") String rollNo);
```

Comment: Something like? `@Query("UPDATE Student c SET c.rollNo= :rollNo WHERE c.id in :ids")
    void updateStudentRollNo(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids, @Param("rollNo") String rollNo);`

Comment: @AlanHay the roll no are also in a list

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `Student` entities where you call the method `updateStudentRollNo`, you may call  `repository.saveAll(students)` , that will make the updates on list. The way you are trying to do is not possible, because each student have a different rollNo, so batch update like that can't be done.

Comment: But the student entities has other properties too.So  save all with just roll no won't work for me.

Comment: So you are doing the best possible way, iterating over the list and calling updateStudentRollNo.